# set column to full height of the page not exceeding the page size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar on the top and set the html and body to height 100% and i seperated the page into two columns using bootstrap grid and I want to set the height of the two columns that it should not exceed the page so that No scroll bar appears

How to set the column height so that scroll bar do not appears

Comment: add your HTML Code

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `height: 100%` on the **parent** and **grandparent** and so on. You can see a demo on codepen:

https://codepen.io/k-five/pen/gZgwqO

or here:

```css
html,body{
height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;
}

body > div.parent {
  height: 100%;
}
div.parent > span {
  display: inline-block; width: 50%;
}
div.parent > span:first-child {
  
  height: 100%; background-color: #F00;
}
div.parent > span:last-child {
  height: 100%; background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <body>
    
    <div class="parent">
      <span>1</span><span>2</span>
    </div>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

And if you want to use **bootstrap** take look at 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/ which is `h-100`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried vh?

```
.column2{
    height: 100vh    
}
```

It stands for viewport height, and will be the exact size of the screen you're viewing this on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.row-eq-height` from Bootstrap? Have a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/).

Be warn though that they're using `flex` style so check your supported browsers first before using these kind of css.

```
/*
 * Row with equal height columns
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

One more thing, for classes like these `col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6` you don't have to specify all the breakpoints. Just use `col-xs-6` and it will be applied to all breakpoints hence "mobile first", to save you some code and filesize. Let me know if that helps. ;)